# Wildcard in textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two tables.
1.Test_Cap_Model1
2.Router

I have one report: ReportYield
[image: report view]

In this report I made one control text box that contains code sql statement as below
[image: code]

This code will generate route value from router table if model value in report (its from query that generate from test_cap_model1 table) contain in router.[testmodel].

I tried to do in query but my problem is value of model in test_cap_model1 table are not the same in test model in router table. As example

> Model value in test_cap table = 1471D3BTL-Non HW

but

> Test Model Value in Router table = 1471D3BTL

Comment: First regarding questions on Stack Overflow.  Please do not post code as a linked image.  Instead, learn how to format code properly in the question.  There is a round question mark icon in the top-right corner of the question edit box.  Click that to get help on markdown, or try out the various editor icons.

Comment: Wildcard or DAO (used in Jet by default) is "*", the "%" wildcard used for ADO. Not clear goal of the code used for generating SQL statement, it won't work for data retrieving.

Comment: Second, the code (in the image) is not the correct way to bind a textbox to an SQL statement.  With that code, you will only get the SQL displayed in the textbox.  Please see [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.controlsource).

Answer (score 0):

Use *DLookup* for such tasks, and the *Value* property:

```
Private Sub Text10_Click()

    Me!Text10.Value = DLookup("[Route]", "[Router]", "[Model] Like '" & Me!Model.Value & "*'")

    ' or:
    ' Me!Text10.Value = DLookup("[Route]", "[Router]", "[Model] Like '" & Me!Model.Value & "%'")

End Sub
```

There is nothing to requery. And do change your control names to something meaningful.

Comment: hmmm i already try your code but i cant get the value from the router table :(

Comment: Then there isn't a record with data matching your criteria. Or see edited answer, please, using %.

Comment: I've already try but still can't. i already check these two table and i have matching data.

Comment: Can't tell. It works here, but I don't have your data.